# Content-Editable Directive is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, contenteditable

I am new to `angularjs` . Here, I have a table and I am using `contenteditable` attribute of `HTML5` . Now, I have a following code -

```
<td class="td-report-field" contenteditable="disabledoneButton"
    contextmenu-item="report" context-menu="menuOptions">
  {{ report.attributes.field }}
</td>
```

Here I am trying to use this on the basis of the `disabledoneButton` . Now value of a displayDoneButton is `true` then also it is not making that row as a  editable. Now, I have tried it by using `contenteditable = 'true'` then it starts working , but not on the value of a `disabledoneButton`.

I have a directive as well -

```
 var contentEditable = [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) {
                     return;
                } 
                ngModel.$render = function() {
                    element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                };

            ngModel.$render();

            // Listen for change events to enable binding
            element.bind('blur keypress keyup change', function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });
            // Write data to the model
            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
            }
        }
    };
    }];
```

Can any one please help me to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `contenteditable="{{disabledoneButton}}"`?

Comment: No I have not tried, This one is working .just tried this. can you please tell me the reason behind this ?

Comment: @ ganeshk added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide data-binding to attribute values use [interpolation markup](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) as:

```
contenteditable="{{disabledoneButton}}"
```

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#how-text-and-attribute-bindings-work):

> During the compilation process the [`compiler`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) uses the [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)
>   service to see if text nodes and element attributes contain
>   interpolation markup with embedded expressions.
>
> If that is the case, the compiler adds an interpolateDirective to the
>   node and registers [`watches`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on the computed interpolation function,
>   which will update the corresponding text nodes or attribute values as
>   part of the normal [`digest` cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Comment: Perfect one ...Thanks a lot.. @Stanislav .. Thanks for saving my day ..

Comment: @ganeshk glad it helped you. You can accept the answer then.

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt related to this. How to add one more condition there like -  contenteditable="{{disabledonebutton}} && somethingelse " this is not working

Comment: @ganeshk why not using such expression `{{disabledonebutton  && somethingelse}}`?